# Unable to load DataTable with Dash 0.41

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Since the version 0.41.0 of dash, the following code is on error :

```
import dash

from dash_table_experiments import DataTable

app = dash.Dash()   app.layout = DataTable( id='datatable', rows=[{'V'+dash.__version__: i} for i in range(5)] )

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

whereas version 0.40.0 displays the table properly.

Would any one know what has changed ?

Thanks for your help ;

Answer (score 0):

From the README file on the `dash-table-experiements` github page:

> dash-table-experiments
>
> DEPRECATED
>
> If you are looking for a first class data table component for Dash head on over to https://github.com/plotly/dash-table and check out the documentation https://dash.plot.ly/datatable.

The component is no longer supported. The `dash-table` component works really well, though. Here is a basic example:

```py
import dash
import numpy as np
import pandas

from dash_table import DataTable

app = dash.Dash()

df = pandas.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6))

app.layout = DataTable(id='datatable',
                       columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                       data=df.to_dict(orient='records'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```